# Изменить название метки webapi

Tags: предложение, метки, переименование-метки

Предлагаю добавить дефис в название метки [webapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webapi), чтобы получилось [web-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api). Считаю такой вариант более читабельным и понятным. Так же, этот вариант написания будет соответствовать написанию других меток, состоящих из нескольких слов, например: [google-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api), [база-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85) и т.д.

Comment: Обоснуете, почему так лучше?

Comment: @Kromster, готово

Comment: Хех. Всего 4 вопроса. А не должно ли это вообще стать [tag:asp.net-web-api]?

Answer (score 2):

Для начала хорошо бы разобраться, что это вообще за метка (описание пока отсутствует). Учитывая ничтожное количество вопросов по ней, могу предположить, что на её месте вообще должна быть другая метка, скорее всего [asp.net-web-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api). Не трудно заметить, что дефисы тут уже присутствуют. Если моя догадка верна, то самый простой способ — просто переназначить метки на вопросах. Чуть более сложный — сделать синонимизацию дабы избежать ее появление в будущем.